# How can I set up CI/CD pipeline for Amazon ECS with GitHub Actions for multiple tasks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-actions, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a repo that contains folders for a lot of separate Fargate tasks. Each folder contains all necessary code for its deployment (task code, requirements.txt and dockerfile). Earlier I manually created containers for each task, pushed it to aws repo, created and scheduled tasks on fargate etc. Now I want to automate this process.

I found this article which is very helpful.
https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/containers/create-a-ci-cd-pipeline-for-amazon-ecs-with-github-actions-and-aws-codebuild-tests/

But the problem is that I need a slightly different workflow: when I push changes to repo, it should redeploy only those tasks, which were changed by my commit, not all project.

is there any existing workflow for it? or what can be the best solution? I think splitting all my tasks into different repos should be better, but I have more than 50 different tasks with a lot of common code.

many thanks!

Comment: assuming you have common code in directory A and a task in directory B, how would you know that a change in directory A should trigger a deployment of the task in directory B?

Comment: @rethab yes. actually, that's another problem. I think there're two ways:
1. triggering workflow for each task manually, not after each commit
2. trigger a deployment only if the task directory (not common code directories) is changed. in any case, if I will change anything in the common code, I will have to redeploy all tasks.
overall it all looks dump, that's why I wondering if there's a better way to organize my tasks.

Comment: or maybe I should just redeploy all my tasks on any change... it will take a lot of time I assume, but it will be more reliably.

Comment: This is what we achieved using Pulumi IaC. You describe your infrastructure (ECS Fargate tasks in your case) which Pulumi provisions for you during GHA workflow. If you make a change Pulumi by default provisions only the diff.